# I have a rendering problem with useEffect

Tags: reactjs

```
const handleSearch = (key: searchType, monthVal?: number) => {
    if (key === SearchInfo.MONTH) {
      setMonthVal(monthVal);
    }
    setSearchKey(key as searchType);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchKey !== undefined && domainState) {
      getIncomeInfo(searchKey);
    }
  }, [searchKey, domainState, monthVal]);
```

Two state updates in one method, but only one update in useEffect, I think it should trigger two updates, is there a problem with my understanding?

I think there are two updates to the state, shouldn't USEEFFECT trigger twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your two `setState` calls inside the handler function will be batched. [1]

```
 function handleClick() {
    console.log("=== click ===");
    setCount((c) => c + 1); // Does not re-render yet
    setFlag((f) => !f); // Does not re-render yet
    // React will only re-render once at the end (that's batching!)
  }
```

2. After rendering only once, your `useEffect` will check for dependency change. Since both `monthVal` and `searchKey` have their value changed. It will run the `useEffect`.
3. `useEffect` will only be called once, because the re-render happened once due to batching in React 17. The next re-render has new values of `monthVal` and `searchKey` which causes the `useEffect` to run only once. The array only controls **when** the effect runs, and **not** how many times it should run.

Reference:
1: https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/21

Comment: But the react version of this project is 17

Comment: @曲世杰 If you read the linked discussion, you'll see the batching happens for React 17 too!